# Haskell: Handling resulting Either from computations

Tags: haskell, nested, parsec, either

I have revisited Haskell lateley and constructed a toy programming language parser/interpreter. Using Parsec for lexing and parsing and a separate interpreter. I'm running in to some issues with feeding the result from the parser to my interpreter and handle the potential error from both the interpreter and parser. I end up with something like this:

```
main = do
  fname <- getArgs
  input <- readFile (head fname)
  case lparse (head fname) input of
    Left msg -> putStrLn $ show msg
    Right p -> case intrp p of
      Left msg -> putStrLn $ show msg
      Right r -> putStrLn $ show r
```

This dosn't look pretty at all. My problem is that `lparse` returns `Either ParseError [(String, Stmt)]` and `itrp` returns the type `Either ItrpError Stmt` so I'm having a real hard time feeding the `Right` result from the parser to the interpreter and at the same time bail and print the possible `ParseError` or `IntrpError`.

The closest to what i want is something like this

```
main = do
  fname <- getArgs
  input <- readFile (head fname)
  let prog = lparse (head fname) input
  (putStrLn . show) (intrp <$> prog)
```

But this will not surprisingly yield a nested Either and not print pretty either.

So are there any nice Haskell ideomatic way of doing this threading results from one computation to another and handling errors (`Lefts`) in a nice way without nesting cases?

**Edit**

adding types of `lparse` and `itrp`

```
lparse :: Text.Parsec.Pos.SourceName -> String -> Either Text.Parsec.Error.ParseError [([Char], Stmt)]

intrp :: [([Char], Stmt)] -> Either IntrpError Stmt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not perfect, I'd create a helper function for embedding any `Show`able error from `Either` into [`MonadError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad.Except

strErr :: (MonadError String m, Show e) => Either e a -> m a
strErr = either (throwError . show) return
```

Then if you have a computation that can fail with errors, like

```
someFn :: ExceptT String IO ()
someFn = strErr (Left 42)
```

you can run it (printing errors to *stdout*) as

```
main :: IO ()
main = runExceptT someFn >>= either putStrLn return
```

In your case it'd be something like

```
main = either putStrLn return <=< runExceptT $ do
  fname <- liftIO getArgs
  input <- liftIO $ readFile (head fname)
  prog <- strErr $ lparse (head fname) input
  r <- strErr $ interp prog
  print r
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to chain successful computations, you can always use `>>=` to do that. For instance in your case:

```
lparse (head fname) input >>= intrp
```

And if you want to print out either your error message you can use the `either` class that takes two handler functions, one for the case when you have `Left a` (error in your case) and another for `Right b` (in your case a successful thing). An example:

```
either (putStrLn . show) (putStrLn . show) (lparse (head fname) input >>= intrp)
```

And if anything fails in your chain (any step of your monadic chain becomes `Left a`) it stops and can for instance print out the error message in the above case.

Comment: You probably want to use `hPutStrLn stderr` in place of `putStrLn` in the `Left` case, so that the error message goes to standard error instead of standard output.

Comment: @chepner, probably. I am just doing what the OP is doing. But yeah, better to use `hPutStrLn stderr` in case of error messages.

Comment: Cannot use `>>=` in this case since the types of `lparse` and `intrp` are different. i.e ``lparse
  :: SourceName -> String -> Either ParseError [([Char], Stmt)]`` and ``intrp :: [([Char], Stmt)] -> Either IntrpError Stmt``

Comment: @Patrik, care to provide the types in the opening message?

Comment: @sham1, added it in the comment above and edited the original post.